# disable or cancel combobox SelectedIndexChanged event with code?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I need to working with combobox SelectedIndexChanged event, but in some cases I want when click button cancel SelectedIndexChanged event or code related to this event stop working ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ComboBox comboBox = new  ComboBox();
```

Subscribe to **SelectedIndexChanged** event

```
comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Use below code to unsubscribe the **SelectedIndexChanged**  event

```
comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are number of options

1. You can unsubscribe the event temporarily
2. You can maintain a flag to check whether you need to process it or not.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can disable/enable the combobox, on the basis of button click
2. You can unsubscribe the `SelectedIndexChanged` as told by @Ramashankar
3. Maintain a flag to check whether event has to be executed or not

Answer (score 0):

You can unsubscribe the events like the below upon clicking on the button:

```
combo1.SelectedIndexChanged -= combo1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```