# Silverlight ComboBox SelectionChange triggers on Form_BeginningEdit

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, combobox, selectionchanged

I would like to ask how can I disable the combobox selectionchange event from triggering when I begin to edit my form.

The problem here is that when I edit my form, the selectionchange also triggers which I believe causes my comboboxes to have a null value.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: You edit form means, when you start typing the text in ur combo-box? right.

Comment: I just click the Edit icon but I haven't changed anything yet on my ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

You can unsubscribe the Combobox Selection changed event and resubscribe it from code behind.

```
ComboBox comboBox = new  ComboBox();
```

Subscribe to **SelectedIndexChanged** event

```
comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Use below code to unsubscribe the **SelectedIndexChanged**  event

```
comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

[disable or cancel combobox SelectedIndexChanged event with code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21256690/1172862)